# Disable VSCode automatic updates but allow other User Settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am packaging Microsoft Visual Studio Code for an enterprise environment and part of our packaging requirements is to disable automatic updates and lock down the ability for users to turn on automatic updates. From all documentation that I have been able to find, it seems that the only way to turn off automatic updates in VSCode is to add the following to the User Settings in the settings.json file:

```
{
    "update.channel": "none"
}
```

The problem is that in order to prevent users from changing this setting I will have to lock down this file, which will prevent users from being able to make any other customizations they may want such as changing the theme or adding preferences to other extensions such as ESLint or Pretter. Is there a way to lock down turning off automatic updates while also allowing users to customize VSCode to their liking?